Proper conditional chaining in Polars
I have this piece of code that conditionally applies additional manipulations against a column ('NaicsDescription'). I am not sure if it is the best / cleanest way I should be doing this in Polars. Even though it seems to work and would appreciate some guidance.
The idea is this to...

apply the lowercase operation on the column,
conditionally apply some additional operations,
and finally finish up with some additional common operations.

Is this correct?
import polars as pl
from unicodedata import normalize 
from lingua import Language, LanguageDetectorBuilder
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

languages = [Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH]
detector = LanguageDetectorBuilder.from_languages(*languages).build()

test = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
        "NaicsDescription": ['Full service restuarants', 'The Manufacturing of toys and trains', 'POWER GENERATING STATIONS', 'the short term rental of cottages']
    }
)


def lang_identifier(text: str):
    '''
    Language identification of text. This is just a simple wrapper around lingua function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    text : str
        Input string to identify language for.

    Returns
    -------
    language : str
        Returns either 'EN' or 'FR' or None if input text is not of type string.

    '''
    language = None
    if isinstance(text, str):
        language = detector.detect_language_of(text)
        if language:
            language = language.iso_code_639_1.name
    return language


en_stopwords = '|'.join(set(w.lower() for w in stopwords.words('english')))
fr_stopwords = '|'.join(set(w.lower() for w in stopwords.words('french')))
bilingual_stopwords = '|'.join(set(w.lower() for w in stopwords.words('english') + stopwords.words('french')))

test = test.with_columns(
pl.col('NaicsDescription')
    .str.to_lowercase().alias('NaicsDescription_')
    ).with_columns(
        pl.when(pl.col('NaicsDescription').map_elements(lang_identifier, return_dtype=pl.String) == 'FR')
        .then(
            pl.col('NaicsDescription_').str.replace_all(r'\b(?:' + fr_stopwords + r')\b', ' ')
            )
        .when(pl.col('NaicsDescription').map_elements(lang_identifier, return_dtype=pl.String) == 'EN')
        .then(
            pl.col('NaicsDescription_').str.replace_all(r'\b(?:' + en_stopwords + r')\b', ' ')
            )
        .otherwise(
            pl.col('NaicsDescription_').str.replace_all(r'\b(?:' + bilingual_stopwords + r')\b', ' ')
            )
        ).with_columns(
            pl.col('NaicsDescription_').map_elements(lambda x: normalize('NFKD',x)
                        .encode('ascii', errors='ignore')
                        .decode('utf-8'), return_dtype=pl.String)
            .str.replace_all(r'(?:[^\s\w]|_\d)+', ' ')
            .str.replace_all(r'\b(?:\d+|\w{1,2})\b', ' ')
            .str.replace_all(r'\s\s+', ' ')
            .str.strip_chars()
            .replace('', None)
    )

edit: full working example added...

It seems likely that the different instances of pl.Expr.map_elements can be written in native polars. If you provided a more complete runnable example along with the expected output, it'd be easier to answer.

It is hard to say without seeing any data whether there is a better way to approach what you are doing or whether any steps can be optimised. In future, a runnable example does make it a lot easier to help.
It does seem like each step depends on the last. Generally avoid map_elements unless your logic cannot be expressed in polars expressions. In this case, it seems like your lang_identifier function would not likely be able to be expressed as a polars expression, but impossible to be certain. Your unicode normalization seems to be the best approach and in line with this SO answer.
I think more than anything, this code can be refactored so the intent is clearer and repeated operations such as identifying the language and removing stopwords are factored out to a function or a variable.
Here is my attempt at that. It shouldn't change anything, just a refactor. It probably isn't perfect as I haven't been able to run it.
def remove_stopwords(text: pl.Expr, stopwords: str) -> pl.Expr:
    """Removes supplied stopwords from a string."""
    return text.str.replace_all(r"\b(?:" + stopwords + r")\b", " ")


naics_description = pl.col("NaicsDescription")
naics_description_lower = pl.col("NaicsDescription").str.to_lowercase()

identified_language = naics_description.map_elements(
    lang_identifier,
    return_dtype=pl.String,
)

naics_description_stopwords_removed = (
    pl.when(identified_language == "FR")
    .then(remove_stopwords(naics_description_lower, fr_stopwords))
    .when(identified_language == "EN")
    .then(remove_stopwords(naics_description_lower, en_stopwords))
    .otherwise(remove_stopwords(naics_description_lower, bilingual_stopwords))
)

test = test.with_columns(
    naics_description_stopwords_removed.map_elements(
        lambda x: normalize("NFKD", x).encode("ascii", errors="ignore").decode("utf-8"),
        return_dtype=pl.String,
    )
    .str.replace_all(r"(?:[^\s\w]|_\d)+", " ")
    .str.replace_all(r"\b(?:\d+|\w{1,2})\b", " ")
    .str.replace_all(r"\s\s+", " ")
    .str.strip_chars()
    .replace("", None)
)


One thing that I question and struggle with is the performance of the regex matching in the str.replace_all lines and now in the remove_stopwords function.  With Pandas, I would make sure to compile the regex beforehand only once and feed that to the Pandas str.replace function.  Not sure if I should be worried about this as I am not fully aware of how Polars might handle and deal with this performance wise under the hood.

using this method does work well and is easier to read, I have tested against 100K records of my dataframe of almost 7 million.  Performance is reasonable, however when I add in an additional map_elements to a function that does lemmatization (using spacy models) the performace drops drastically to about 7 mins for 100K input.   My understanding is that lemmatization in general is costly and might be something I will have to live without...but wish I can workaround the map_elements if I can.

Regarding the performance of the regex replacing, my understanding is Polars does this in Rust, so it will be quite performant. If your regex replaces aren't dependant on the previous one, you can use .str.replace_many to do them all at once, which I imagine would be a further speed up.
The main performance hit would be any usage of map_elements. This goes back to Python and you lose parallelisation. It is orders of magnitude slower than anything you do in native Polars. Do as much as you possible can with Polars expressions, however I understand this may not be possible for NLP stuff.

It may be worth taking a look whether there are Polars plugins support what you are trying to do. Staying in Polars (or at least numpy or other arrow compatible formats such as DuckDB) will keep your code from looping element by element (which is really what map_elements does).
This extension seems to implement some NLP stuff.
